# How do I get the Remote Electrical Charge Gadget Challenges?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm having some trouble with 2 of the Remote Electrical Charge Gadget Challenges (not the Combat Challenges), namely:

- Use the Remote Electrical Charge to force an enemy to hit another enemy (3 required)
- Use the Remote Electrical Charge to blast one armored thug into any other thug

I've already acquired this one:

- Use the Remote Electrical Charge to get an armed enemy to fire his weapon and surprise at least one other nearby enemy

I wasn't in melee combat for that one, but I'm wondering if I need to be for these other two because I just can't seem to get them. I've stalked several enemies with guns from afar attempting to force one enemy to shoot another. I don't even know how I'm supposed to know whether or not an enemy has hit another or not.

Do I need to be in melee combat for these challenges and not do them from afar? Is there some trick that I am missing? Am I just unlucky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to be in combat for any of these, the end result is all that matters.

The armored challenge is pretty simple. Any enemy in body armor (armor is highlighted yellow in detective mode) will fly back in the direction of the charge blast. So if Batman is in combat with an armored enemy, do the quick REC blast (Xbox 360: <kbd>LT</kbd><kbd>Ⓑ</kbd>, PS3: <kbd>L1</kbd><kbd>◯</kbd>) and he should go flying backwards. If you make sure he is positioned between you and some other enemies you will get the challenge easy.

As for causing an enemy to hit another, the outlined strategy for hitting one of the Lieutenants is a good one. But it will work well on any tight group of enemies wielding weapons.

Comment: The quick REC blast on Xbox 360 is actually LT+B, not A. I've mostly been focusing on trying to get this with enemies with guns, not melee weapons! Is it even possible with guns then or not?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Dammit! I'm always getting SNES Ⓐ confused with Xbox 360 Ⓑ!!! >:(

Comment: And on the PS3 it's L1+◯. :P

Comment: @Ullallulloo Wait, I thought the bottom trigger on the PS3 is L2, did they change that from the PS2?

Comment: @CyberSkull: No, the positions are the same on both, L2 is the one behind that swings, but that puts you in detective mode.

Comment: @Ullallulloo Ok, so the controls are reversed from the Xbox 360 version. In that one the LB (top left shoulder) is detective mode and LT (bottom left shoulder) is for using gadgets.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed the "blast thug into other thug", but the other one is pretty simple, you have to use the REC on the hammer carrying enemies when they're around other thugs, when they'll get electrified they'll swing their hammers and hopefully hit at least three enemies.